# java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/salesforce/ant/SFDCAntTask, method: doLogin signature: ()Lcom/sforce/soap/partner/LoginResult;)

Tags: sandbox, metadata, ant, migration-tool, continuous-integration

```
C:\Users\rajiv\Downloads\salesforce_ant_40.0\sample\build.xml:14: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/salesforce/ant/SFDCAntTask, method: doLogin signature: ()Lcom/sforce/soap/partner/LoginResult;) catch_type not a subclass of Throwable
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:579)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:237)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.execute(Antlib.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:428)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:277)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:832)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)
```

Total time: 0 seconds

When I am trying to retrieve code from Sandbox.Am getting the above error.

Comment: So you are using ant to get metadata from your sandbox and the ant script fails. please share your script so we can find errors in it

Answer (score 0):

Connection Error was due to proxy firewall between Salesforce & Ant